# How do I prevent a mouseenter function from triggering until a mouseleave function is done?

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

First, I can't provide a fiddle because the chrome console is returning "Undefined is not a function" a million times and there's no way to stop it.
I am using MacRabbit Espresso, and there doesn't seem to be an issue with the function working as written in that console:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sponsored_ad').on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500, function(){
            $('.info_div', this).show("slide", { direction: "down" },500);
        });
    });

    $('.sponsored_ad').on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.70 }, 500, function(){
            $('.info_div', this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 100);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="ad_container"> 
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="blackad.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Greg</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="redad.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Brad</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="bluead.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Linda</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="greenad.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Jason</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="blackad.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Kathleen</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="redad.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Percy</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="bluead.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is Bruce</div></div>
    <div class="sponsored_ad"><img src="greenad.png" alt="" /> <div class="info_div">Hello, my name is John</div></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#ad_container{
    width: 620px;
    /*text-align: justify;*/
}
.sponsored_ad {
    height: 195px;
    width: 195px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    position: relative;
}

.info_div {
    width:195px; 
    height:195px; 
    background-color:#4a4a4a; 
    color:#FFF;  
    text-align:center;  
    opacity:0.95;  
    filter:alpha(opacity=95); 
    position:absolute;  
    bottom:0px;   
    display:none; 
}
```

My first problem is that I don't want to set off the mouseenter trigger until the cursor has come to rest on the div with the class "sponsored_ad". The second problem, probably related to the first, is that I don't want a mousenter event to trigger until the most recent mouseout event is finished.

Wrapping the mouseenter code in a setTimeOut function stopped the mouseout event from firing at all.

I also tried to refactor using hoverIntent, using the code from the git site exactly, but that did not work (also, for a reason beyond me, the $(this) refrenced the entire document even though it should have referenced only $('sponsored_ad')

Obviously I know enough jQuery to be dangerous. Any help at all is very appreciated.

Comment: tl;dr By setting a flag

Comment: Here : http://jsfiddle.net/f72h3mmr/

Comment: @Jonathan  Do you suggest using the hasClass method?